# jquery ui droppable : how to dropp an element outside a div with overflow:hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I know how to use [jquery ui droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/).

But i'm not sur if it's possible to do this :

[see a live example with this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/rrn6L/1/)

I have a list of element in a div which is in overflow:hidden :

html :

```
<div id="list">
    <p id="draggable_1">Element 1</p>
    <p id="draggable_2">Element 2</p>
    <p id="draggable_3">Element 3</p>
</div>
```

css :

```
#list
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

javascript / jQuery :

```
$("#draggable_1").draggable();
$titre_track_1.droppable({
    drop: function () {
        alert("dropped");
    }
});
```

If i try to dropp an element like draggable_1 outside the div #list, the element is not visible. It's logic because the parent is in overflow:hidden

do you know if it's possible to drop that element outside  ? I need to have this div with overflow:hidden

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly your desired outcome. What exactly do you want to happen when you drop the element of the list?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind I want to simply dropp the element outside the list. Actually, if i move the element outside the list, it becomes invisible because of the overflow:hidden The example is very basic because the target is not important in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use clone helper to clone element on drag start and append it to the body with `appendTo` option:

```
$("#draggable_1").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: 'body',
    start: function(e){
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    },
    stop: function(){
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xYQ9c/

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Thank you, you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Sweet. Just need to add a transition to the elements for their return to get the same effect as a normal `draggable`